# show no of available rooms in a hotel under each room type

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is a multi hotel booking site like [agoda.com](http://agoda.com).

I have been able to get all the hotel room types..but now i have a **problem** on showing **no of rooms** available **for each room type**.

Table structure is like below.

**Room types table**

```
room_id  || name || max || hotel_id || no_rooms 
   1         a       4        01           4
   2         b       1        02           2
   3         c       2        01           3
   4         d       4        02           4
   5         e       4        04           10
```

**Bookings table**

```
id  || room_type_id ||  hotel_id ||      check_in      ||  check_out
1           1             01       2015-03-18 11:26:04   2015-03-20 11:26:04
2           1             01       2015-03-19 10:28:04   2015-03-25 10:28:04
3           2             01       2015-03-19 10:28:04   2015-03-25 10:28:04
4           3             02       2015-03-19 10:28:04   2015-03-25 10:28:04
```

So I want to show it like below

If a user searches for a hotel selecting **check-in date** and **check-out date** then it will show the hotels list. When a user clicks on one hotel it will show the **room types** and in each hotel room type it will **show the no rooms available**..**like below**

[image]

**when user select no of rooms** :

[image]

also I have been able to show the bookings like this. But this is not how I wanted

```
SELECT * FROM bookings bk 
JOIN room_types rt ON rt.room_id = bk.room_type_id 
WHERE bk.hotel_id = '" . (int)$hotelid . "' 
AND bk.check_in 
NOT BETWEEN  '".$chkin."' 
AND '".$chkout."' 
AND bk.check_out 
NOT BETWEEN '".$chkin."' 
AND '".$chkout."' 
AND (bk.check_in >= '".$chkin."' OR bk.check_out <= '".$chkout."')
```

Comment: We are not here to create a website for you. Show us the code which you have tried and the problem which you are facing.

Comment: i have added the code now @ughai

Comment: It's unclear what you want. Let's get rid of the images and the php stuff for now. Focus on the sql bit. What is the desired result set? Proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) would be useful. Also, remember that time is linear.